# Counting/Probability of Picking Chairs (Answer validation)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, combinations, conditional-probability

> In a room, there are 16 wooden chairs and 10 plastic chairs. Except for
> the color, the wooden chairs are identical and the same holds for the
> plastic chairs. Of the wooden chairs, 5 are red, 5 are blue and 6 are
> green. Of the plastic chairs, 4 are red, 2 are blue and 4 are green.

Question 1:

> In how many different ways can 9 chairs be chosen from the total
> number of 26 chairs in the room such that there are 3 of each color?

Question 2:

> What is the probability that only one of the 9 chosen chairs is
> wooden?

My try for question 1:

$${9 \choose 3}{7 \choose 3}{10 \choose 3} = 352,800$$

My try for question 2:

Let A be the event of picking 1 wooden and 8 plastic chairs.
Let B be the event of picking 9 chairs with exactly 3 colors each.

$$\Pr(A \cap B) = \dfrac{{16 \choose 1}{10 \choose 8}}{{26 \choose 9}}$$
$$\Pr(B) = \dfrac{352,800}{{26 \choose 9}}$$
$$\Pr(A|B) = \dfrac{{16 \choose 1}{10 \choose 8}}{352,800} = \dfrac{1}{490}$$

The probability for question 2 seems too small. Can someone point out my mistake?

Comment: Your expression for $\Pr(A\cap B)$ is actually just $\Pr(A)$. These are different because $A$ is not a subset of $B$. Try counting the elements of $A\cap B$ in three groups based on the color of the wooden chair.

Comment: Let's suppose I'm picking 1 red wooden, 2 red plastic, 3 blue plastic, and 3 green plastic chairs then there are $\binom{5}{1} \binom{4}{2} \binom{6}{3} \binom{2}{3} = 240$ ways. 
Then I wold do the same for the other 2 colors. Is this the right direction?

Comment: If only one chair is wooden, and we get 3 for each color, we know the the wooden one is blue. It should appear somewhere in your process.

Comment: For Question 1, your answer is correct, but I think we want something different. We want :  Number of wooden red chairs can be from $0$ to $3$, wooden blue chairs can be from $1$ to $3$ , and number of wooden green chairs can be from $0$ to $3$. Number of plastic chairs for each color is known when we decide number of woden chairs for each color.  So total number is $4 \times 3 \times 4=48$.  And it is a good introduction for question 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Karl pointed out in the comments, we have to consider the color of the wooden chair when calculating $\Pr(A \cap B)$.  There are three possibilities:

- one red wooden chair, two red plastic chairs, three blue plastic chairs, and three green plastic chairs
- three red plastic chairs, one blue wooden chair, two blue plastic chairs, and three green plastic chairs
- three red plastic chairs, three blue plastic chairs, one green wood chair, and two green plastic chairs

Since there are only two blue chairs, the first and third cases cannot occur.  Therefore, the number of ways exactly one wooden chair can be selected if three chairs of each color are selected is
$$|A \cap B| = \dbinom{4}{3}\dbinom{5}{1}\binom{2}{2}\dbinom{4}{3}$$

You correctly found that the number of ways of selecting three chairs of each color is
$$|B| = \binom{9}{3}\binom{7}{3}\binom{10}{3}$$
and that the number of elements in the sample space is
$$|S| = \binom{26}{9}$$

Hence, the probability that exactly one of the nine chairs selected is wooden given that three chairs of each color are selected is
\begin{align*}
\Pr(A \mid B) & = \frac{\Pr(A \cap B)}{\Pr(B)}\\ 
              & = \frac{\frac{|A \cap B|}{|S|}}{\frac{|B|}{|S|}}\\ 
              & = \frac{|A \cap B|}{|B|}\\
              & = \frac{\dbinom{4}{3}\dbinom{5}{1}\dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{4}{3}}{\dbinom{9}{3}\dbinom{7}{3}\dbinom{10}{3}}
\end{align*}